# Index $i$ such that $\prod_{k=1}^p a_k+a_i$ is divisible by $p^2$

Tags: number-theory

> Let $p$ be an odd prime, and $a_1,a_2,\ldots,a_n$ be a series of integers in arithmetic progression whose common difference is not divisible by $p$. Prove that there exists an index $i$ such that $\displaystyle\prod_{k=1}^p a_k+a_i$ is divisible by $p^2$.

Since $a_1,a_2,\ldots,a_n$ are in arithmetic progression with say common difference $d$, we have the sequence to be $a_1,a_1+d,a_1+2d,\ldots,a_1+(n-1)d$. We then have $$\displaystyle\prod_{k=1}^p a_k+a_i = a_1(a_1+d) \cdots (a_1+(n-1)d)+a_i.$$ How do we continue?

Answer (score 3):

Since the common difference is coprime to $p$, we have that the $a_{1}, \dots, a_{p}$ are congruent in some order to $0, 1, \dots, p-1$ modulo $p$. Suppose it is $a_{i} \equiv 0 \pmod{p}$.

Now the product of $a_{1}, \dots, a_{p}$ except $a_{i}$ is congruent to $-1 \pmod{p}$ by [Wilson's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wilson's_theorem):
$$
\prod_{k \ne i} a_{k} = -1 + p c
$$
for some $c$,
so that the product of all $a_{1}, \dots, a_{p}$ is congruent to $- a_{i} \pmod{p^{2}}$:
$$
\prod_{k} a_{k}
=
a_{i} \prod_{k \ne i} a_{k} = a_{i} (-1 + p c)
\equiv - a_{i} \pmod{p^{2}},
$$
as $p \mid a_{i}$.

Hence 
$$
\prod_{k=1}^p a_k+a_i \equiv 0 \pmod{p^{2}}.
$$

Summing it up: choose the unique $i$ such that $p \mid a_{i}$.

Comment: No way, then. But I thought that your $n$ was the same as $p$, really.

Answer (score 0):

Hint : $\{a_{1}, \dots, a_{p}\}$ forms a complete residue system mod $p$ and so $\prod_{k=1}^{p}a_{k}\equiv\prod_{k=1}^{p}k\equiv p!\equiv -p \,(mod\,p^{2})$ by Wilson's theorem.

Comment: How do we choose $a_i$?

Comment: @Puzzled417 Sorry I was little confused. Maybe we have to choose $a_{i}$ which is divisible by $p$.